# Number input type that takes only integers?

Tags: jquery, html, validation, jquery-tools

I'm using the jQuery Tools [Validator](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/validator/index.html) which implements HTML5 validations through jQuery.

It's been working great so far except for one thing. In the HTML5 specification, the *input* type `"number"` can have both integers and floating-point numbers.

This seems incredibly short-sighted since it will only be a useful validator when your database fields are signed floating-point numbers (for unsigned ints you'll have to fall back to `pattern` validation and thus lose extra features like the up and down arrows for browsers that support it).

Is there another *input* type or perhaps an *attribute* that would **restrict** the input to just unsigned **integers**?

I couldn't find any.

---

Setting the step to 1 is not the answer since it doesn't restrict the input. You can still type a negative floating-point number into the textbox.

Also, I am aware of pattern validation (I mentioned it in my original post), but that was not part of the question.

I wanted to know if HTML5 allowed restricting an input of type "number" to positive integer values. To this question the answer, it seems, would be "no, it does not".

I didn't want to use pattern validation because this causes some drawbacks when using *jQuery* Tools validation, but it now seems that the specification doesn't allow for a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: As of 2019—I don't know since when—the `number` input (in FF/Chrome/Safari at least) now only accepts integers by default, _unless_ you set an explicit value for the `step` attr that allows decimal values; e.g: `step="0.01"`. [Documented MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#step). In two minds about this because I think it's a sensible default, but also a breaking change (yes, it has affected some code I wrote).

Comment: @DarraghEnright Chrome 87 allows non integers to be entered when `step="1"`. MDN says the behavior is up to the browser.

Answer (score 399):

The best you can achieve with HTML only ([documentation](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/number)):

```html
<input type="number" min="0" step="1"/>
```

Comment: You should probably set `min` to `1` as he wants positive numbers (and not non-negative numbers).

Comment: @pwdst I'll second that. `<input type="number" min="0" step="1"/>` is the most correct answer to the question. Anyway, what's the point in having both `step="1"` and `pattern="\d+"`? I can't type in floating point numbers in either cases.

Comment: @pwdst @DanishAshfaq If this pattern attribute is not in the specification for `type="number"` then this answer is wrong. Anyway, it looks like the standard `<input type="number" min="0" step="1">` is working better than before in Chrome and Firefox. Should I remove the pattern thing?

Comment: I've tested it in Chrome and Firefox, and there is no need for a pattern attribute. In Chrome, without using the pattern attribute, if I type in "4.23", it even gives me a hint: "Please enter a correct value. The closest ones are 4 and 5." But when using the pattern attribute, it just says "Please enter a correct value." So I guess you could update your answer :)

Comment: This did not worked for me on latest version of chrome. It does not allow letters to be typed, but it does allow special characters to be inserted.

Comment: Why I can type e in

Comment: @grantsun for exponential numbers e.g. 10e20.

Comment: This is not right if you want to "restrict the input to just unsigned integers". The "step" attribute will control the increment/decrement of the input value using the keyboard arrows. It will not prevent decimal input values.

Comment: This _is_ the correct answer, but if you want to get the correct integer output from this input, you have to use the DOM API appropriately. First, validate: `input.checkValidity()`. If this returns `false`, then you don’t have an integer, so reject this. Then, get the value as a number: `input.valueAsNumber`. Note that an empty input will be treated as valid, because this input field is optional. If you don’t want that, add the `required` attribute.

Answer (score 229):

Set the `step` attribute to `1`:

```html
<input type="number" step="1" />
```

This seems a bit buggy in Chrome right now so it might not be the best solution at the moment.

A better solution is to use the `pattern` attribute, that uses a regular expression to match the input:

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" />
```

`\d` is the regular expression for a number, `*` means that it accepts more than one of them.

Comment: On Chrome 18, running Ubuntu, the fiddle above does not seem to work. The number attribute does, however.

Comment: @Zut Works for me. (Chrome 18 and Ubuntu.) Did you actually enter something into the input? Use `<input type="text" pattern="\d+" required />` if you don't want to accept an empty input.

Comment: Correction: I'm using Chromium, and not Chrome. I don't suppose it should change anything though.

I can type any arbitrary character in the input field. I just double checked, and have now successfully typed "asdf123,.-".

Comment: @Zut HTML5 validation doesn't stop you from entering those keys. It just prevents the form from being send with those characters. If you submit a form with an input of the type `number` that contains other characters, then Chrome will show you an error message.

Comment: @dotweb - I see your point. The difference between the two is that with the number attribute, all alphabetic characters are automatically removed when I deselect (trigger blur) for the input. This does not happen when using the pattern attribute. I guess this distinction is only important if you are using AJAX to post your data, and you're using some other event than `submit` to trigger the post.

Comment: How is this preventing entering negative numbers? Isn't 'unsigned integers' mean no negatives?

Comment: You can combine the two: <input type="number" min="0" pattern="\d*" />

Comment: if i use pattern like pattern="\d{3,4}" and then want to restrict user to min value 500 and max value 1500, so what to do?

Comment: To allow negative numbers, use a pattern like `-?\d*`

Comment: Its still buggy in chrome

Comment: This does not do what OP asked. **Only integers** `/\d*/.test(1.1) // true`

Comment: @vsync `pattern="\d*"` is not the same as `/\d*/`, `pattern="\d*"` is equal to `/^(?:\d*)$/`, please refer to [HTML5 *pattern* attribute documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-pattern-attribute).

Comment: Does not work. Upvoted this. Then tested in my project. And now can not downwote:(

Answer (score 47):

```
<input type="text" name="PhoneNumber" pattern="[0-9]{10}" title="Phone number">
```

Using this code, the input to the text field limits to enter only digits. Pattern is the new attribute available in HTML 5.

[Pattern attribute doc](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

Comment: According to [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) the **pattern attribute** can only be used where the input type is Text, Search, URL, Telephone, E-mail, Password (as shown here with the "Text" type). This means that semantics of the number input type and therefore (importantly) the numeric on-screen keyboards of some tablets and phones is lost when using this method.

Comment: This on firefox 36.0 allows you to type letters and special characters.

Comment: It doesn't limit input to numbers only, you can still type letters!

Answer (score 46):

The easy way using JavaScript:

```
<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" >
```

Comment: I dont understand `replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')`

Comment: This is important to accept float numbers and repeat `.` only once, e.g. `123.556` can be writen.

Comment: @TarekKalaji - questions states **integers** and not **float numbers**

Comment: how about mobile device? because type text display all keyboards (alfanumeric chars also)

Comment: Inline event handlers like `oninput` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Please _never_ suggest or encourage these attributes. The last browser that still needs them reached end of life nearly two decades ago.

Answer (score 45):

```html
<input type="number" oninput="this.value = Math.round(this.value);"/>
```

Comment: Bro, this solution is key! Thank you!

Comment: The best solution.

Comment: Inline event handlers like `oninput` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Please _never_ suggest or encourage these attributes. The last browser that still needs them reached end of life nearly two decades ago. Also, this erases the value and replaces it with `0` on every invalid input. Bad usability.

Answer (score 44):

Pattern is nice but if you want to restrict the input to numbers only with type="text", you can use oninput and a regex as below:

```
<input type="text" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');" id="myId"/>
```

I warks for me :)

Comment: Beware that this approach might negate your (change) method (event handler) and also erase your default value in the input box.

Comment: Inline event handlers like `oninput` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Please _never_ suggest or encourage these attributes. The last browser that still needs them reached end of life nearly two decades ago.

Answer (score 21):

This is not only for HTML5. This works fine in all browsers. Try this:

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
```

Comment: This is bad. On the input try: Shift+Home, Shift+End, Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V. Use `oninput` instead

Comment: When this answer was written, HTML5 was not published. @zanderwar

Comment: I try just now and IT WORKS! Thank You.

Answer (score 13):

Pattern are always preferable for restriction, try `oninput` and `min` occur 1 for inputting only numbers from 1 onwards

```
<input type="text" min="1" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');"
                                value=${var} >
```

Comment: It is very instresting solution. What for ` value=${var}` is?

Comment: @AcademyofProgrammer example default value for that input

Comment: best answer! works for pasting, works even in IE (10+), gives you the freedom to display any keyboard via the input's type, and does not make chrome display these pesky up/down arrows inside the field.

Answer (score 13):

## Shortest

This is size improvement of [R. Yaghoobi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62351420/860099)

```html
<input type="number" oninput="this.value|=0"/>
```

We use here standard shorthand for "OR" operator e.g `9 | 2 = 11`  in binary: `0b1001 | 0b1010 = 0b1011` . This operator first cast numbers to integers in implicit way and then do OR. But because OR with zero don't change anything so number is cast to integer. OR with non-number string gives 0.

Comment: Kielczewski Which operator is this?

Comment: Outstanding! Good job! Thanks!

Comment: This is by far the best answer. Not only deals with the problem in a short, simple way; it also deals with localization issues (e.g. 100,5 vs 100.5 depending on what country you're from) which most other answers don't.

Comment: you can add a dot

Comment: the only problem with this solution is that it moves the caret in the beginning after the user tries to enter an invalid character a.k.a. decimal point or letter, etc.

Comment: Inline event handlers like `oninput` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Please _never_ suggest or encourage these attributes. The last browser that still needs them reached end of life nearly two decades ago.

Answer (score 8):

Just putting it in your input field : `onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'`

Comment: Maybe you have other problems.

Comment: No. Your proposal does not handle case when I just paste value to the field. It handles only case when I enter value digit by digit.

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onkeypress` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Please _never_ suggest or encourage these attributes. The last browser that still needs them reached end of life nearly two decades ago.

Comment: The global [`event`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/event) and the [`keypress` event](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) are deprecated.

Comment: Nice this is best solution , good old return false. This answer gives  no blinking solution, perfect prevent ! `addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
 if(e.key == "Backspace") {
  // pass
 } else {
  e.preventDefault()
  return false;
 }
})` this also gives no blink solution and laso allow manipulate with keyCode

Answer (score 4):

Set `step` attribute to any float number, e.g. 0.01 and you are good to go.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but the accessible (and now supported in most browsers) version would be:

```html
<input type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

See https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2020/02/24/why-the-gov-uk-design-system-team-changed-the-input-type-for-numbers/

Comment: The pattern you have used only allows integers between 0 and 9. It doesn't allow negatives or values greater than 9

Comment: @Ted The * in the pattern means 0 or more repetitions, meaning eg. 10 or 2134 are also allowed. Additionally, the question specifically asks for unsigned numbers, ie. no negatives - if you want to allow negative numbers the pattern would be `pattern="-?[0-9]*"`.

Comment: that might be, but it still didn't work correctly when using validators. It wouldn't allow values greater than 9. I replaced the pattern with `pattern="\d*"` and it now works fine

Answer (score 3):

have you tried setting the `step` attribute to 1 like this

```
<input type="number" step="1" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `step="any"` . Works fine.
Reference :http://blog.isotoma.com/2012/03/html5-input-typenumber-and-decimalsfloats-in-chrome/

Answer (score 3):

I was working oh Chrome and had some problems, even though I use html attributes. I ended up with this js code

```
$("#element").on("input", function(){
        var value = $(this).val();

        $(this).val("");
        $(this).val(parseInt(value));

        return true;
});
```

Comment: I ended up using this as well with 1 minor tweak; I changed parseInt(value) to parseInt(value.replace('.', ''). This allowed me to paste 1.56 and keep the displayed value at 156 instead of 1.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it does not fit every use case, but

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" />
```

can do a fine job: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2nvqm8x/5/).

Check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range).

Comment: @ViacheslavDobromyslov Not sure what you are looking for, but I remind you the OP question: "Is there another input _type_ or perhaps an _attribute_ that would **restrict** the input to just unsigned **integers**?"
Why do you sentence this answer as "not working", if it does **exactly** what the OP asked?

Comment: Because it's near to impossible to input a value from ~9 quadrillion integers using the proposed range input control.

Comment: @ViacheslavDobromyslov Where this 9 quadrillions requirement come from? The OP didn't ask about that. This answer replies the OP question, no what you have in mind.

Comment: He has not asked for a solution with 10 numbers in a row. Your solution does not work for any range.

Comment: @ViacheslavDobromyslov It does a good job especially with short ranges. Give it a try, I'm sure it would fit well your necessities.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, HTML5 does. Try this code ([w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="">
  Quantity (between 1 and 5): <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

See the min and max paremeter? I tried it using Chrome 19 (worked) and Firefox 12 (did not work).

Comment: This assumes that you want a known range. But if you wanted _any_ integer value, would this still work?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it is not possible to prevent a user from writing decimal values in your input with HTML only.
You have to use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

[From the specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.number.html)

> `step="any"` or positive floating-point number
>   Specifies the value granularity of the element’s value.

So you could simply set it to `1`:

Comment: I've tried this but the problem is that you can still type a floating point number in the text box.

Comment: So, you need code that blocks the user from typing a decimal point?

Answer (score 1):

```
var valKeyDown;
var valKeyUp;


function integerOnly(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (!e.ctrlKey) {
        var arrIntCodes1 = new Array(96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 8, 9, 116);   // 96 TO 105 - 0 TO 9 (Numpad)
        if (!e.shiftKey) {                          //48 to 57 - 0 to 9 
            arrIntCodes1.push(48);                  //These keys will be allowed only if shift key is NOT pressed
            arrIntCodes1.push(49);                  //Because, with shift key (48 to 57) events will print chars like @,#,$,%,^, etc.
            arrIntCodes1.push(50);
            arrIntCodes1.push(51);
            arrIntCodes1.push(52);
            arrIntCodes1.push(53);
            arrIntCodes1.push(54);
            arrIntCodes1.push(55);
            arrIntCodes1.push(56);
            arrIntCodes1.push(57);
        }
        var arrIntCodes2 = new Array(35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 46);
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, arrIntCodes2) != -1) {
            arrIntCodes1.push(e.keyCode);
        }
        if ($.inArray(code, arrIntCodes1) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

$('.integerOnly').keydown(function (event) {
    valKeyDown = this.value;
    return integerOnly(event);
});

$('.integerOnly').keyup(function (event) {          //This is to protect if user copy-pastes some character value ,..
    valKeyUp = this.value;                          //In that case, pasted text is replaced with old value,
    if (!new RegExp('^[0-9]*$').test(valKeyUp)) {   //which is stored in 'valKeyDown' at keydown event.
        $(this).val(valKeyDown);                    //It is not possible to check this inside 'integerOnly' function as,
    }                                               //one cannot get the text printed by keydown event 
});                                                 //(that's why, this is checked on keyup)

$('.integerOnly').bind('input propertychange', function(e) {    //if user copy-pastes some character value using mouse
    valKeyUp = this.value;
    if (!new RegExp('^[0-9]*$').test(valKeyUp)) {
        $(this).val(valKeyDown);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting it, if anyone requires it in future

```
const negativeValuePrevent = (e) => {
    const charCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if(charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) 
    && charCode !== 46){
      if(charCode < 96 || charCode > 105){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

## Short and user friendly

This solution supports tab, backspace, enter, minus in intuitive way

```html
<input type=text onkeypress="return /^-?[0-9]*$/.test(this.value+event.key)">
```

however it not allow to change already typed number to minus and not handle copy-paste case.

As alternative you can use solution based on [R. Yaghoobi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62351420/860099) which allow to put minus and handle copy-paste case, but it delete whole number when user type forbidden character

```html
<input type=text oninput="this.value= ['','-'].includes(this.value) ? this.value : this.value|0">
```

NOTE: above inline solutions use only in small projects. In other case opaque them in functions and move to your js files.

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Please _never_ suggest or encourage these attributes. The last browser that still needs them reached end of life nearly two decades ago. The [`keypress` event](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) is deprecated.

Comment: @SebastianSimon [update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54769527/860099) yourself

Comment: This isn’t React, Angular, or Vue.js. These are DOM 0 event listeners. They don’t cooperate with modern JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

The integer input would mean that it can only take positive numbers, 0 and negative numbers too. This is how I have been able to achieve this using Javascript keypress.

```
<input type="number" (keypress)="keypress($event, $event.target.value)" >

keypress(evt, value){
  
    if (evt.charCode >= 48 && evt.charCode <= 57 || (value=="" && evt.charCode == 45))       
    {  
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The given code won't allow user to enter alphabets nor decimal on runtime,  just positive and negative integer values.

Answer (score -4):

In the Future™ (see [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-inputmode)),  on user agents that present a keyboard to you, you can restrict a text input to just numeric with `input[inputmode]`.

Comment: `inputmode` is mostly for hand-held devices and will trigger the correct keyboard layout, but for "normal" computers with keyboards, it iwll not prevent entering whatever you want.