# Don't allow typing alphabetic characters in a <input type=number />

Tags: javascript, html, numbers

I need to have a textbox, where, whenever typed inside should ONLY allow numbers [0-9]. I've used `type="number"` which definitely holds the client side validation but also allows to type other alphabets. I can do it by tracking each keydown and matching with regex but I was wondering if there is any way I can restrict to type using only html tags and NOT defining any functions in JavaScript to compare in each keydown?

Code not sufficient to do so is:

```
    <input type="number" id="txt_number" maxlength="70" name="txt_name" placeholder="Number">
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @saideshkilaru it's HTML5

Comment: u can use type="text"

Comment: I've seen a similar issue here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808590/html5-number-input-type-that-takes-only-integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808590/html5-number-input-type-that-takes-only-integers). 
It is suggested to use the pattern attribute : `<input type="text" pattern="\d+" />`. User js-coder says : "`\d` is the regular expression for a number, `*` means that it accepts more than one of them"

Comment: @krishna that won't help :). 

Lapidouce, i had tried it but it just validates with regex but won't stop user to type into the textbox.

Comment: I would suggest allowing the user to enter alphabetic characters and show a validation error. I have yet to understand why most designers/developers think it's a good idea to block the keyboard.  
1. why make the user guess why the keyboard is not working ? A user that knows it's a number doesn't need it. A user that doesn't know it should be a number thinks the keyboard is not working.  
2. If the user inputs 123AZ45R6, he will get 123456. He will not always notice something has happened (since most users don't look at the screen while typing). The resulting 123456 has no meaning anyway.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use  [jquery.numeric](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/) plugin.

See
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891696/jquery-what-is-the-best-way-to-restrict-number-only-input-for-textboxes-all) similar question.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".numeric").numeric();
});
```

Comment: `$('input[type=number]').numeric()` would target all of them, without needing extra classes.

Comment: I think I'm marking this as an answer as this solves the problem. However, for my particular case, I would just need to use it once in my project and would not like to include jquery.numeric.js if it can be done just using HTML5 and jquery.js. Just if there's something :).

Comment: is this helping ? http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number

Comment: Nope, already tried that. Its still letting us to type alphabets. Anyways, thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Actually I like it better with the ".numeric" class, because if I make my inputs "type='number'" they get that annoying up / down set of buttons on the right.

Answer (score 17):

Try this

define javascript function

function for allowed number with decimal as below

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
    && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

function for allowed only number not decimal is as below

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Html

```
<input type="number" id="txt_number" maxlength="70" name="txt_name" placeholder="Number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
```

Comment: Thanks @Sandip, but I was looking after something that will make it not using any javascript function. :)

Comment: @Sandip, your code is allowing to enter decimal, which is not number.

Comment: This seems to prevent the delete key

Comment: Doesn't work on IE and need to account windows numpad as well because it has different keycodes.

Answer (score 3):

input type="number" for getting Numeric Keyboard on Mobile Device

Java-Script

```
function numbersonly(myfield, e)
        {
            var key;
            var keychar;

            if (window.event)
                key = window.event.keyCode;
            else if (e)
                key = e.which;
            else
                return true;

            keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

            // control keys
            if ((key==null) || (key==0) || (key==8) || (key==9) || (key==13) || (key==27) )
                return true;

            // numbers
            else if ((("0123456789").indexOf(keychar) > -1))
                return true;

            // only one decimal point
            else if ((keychar == "."))
            {
                if (myfield.value.indexOf(keychar) > -1)
                    return false;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
```

Html

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return numbersonly(this, event)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers behave differently.  In Chrome the following code:

```
<input type="number" id="txt_number" maxlength="70" name="txt_name" placeholder="Number">
  <input type="submit">
```

will work for you **only** if it is in a form and only after the user clicks the submit button.

Comment: yeah but this is not what I was looking for, it wont restrict user to type other alphabets in anyway. Alternative solution would be answer given by @mihai.coirobea by using element.numeric() by including jquery.numeric.js.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a bit of Javascript, this might help [JS-BIN Demo](http://jsbin.com/ahenur/1/edit):

```
<input type="number" onkeyup="if(!this.checkValidity()){this.value='';alert('Please enter a number')};"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to have your input box inside a form and with a submit button. The form validation happens at the submission of the form. See a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ds345/Q4muA/1/

```
<form>Number:
    <input type="number" name="Number" value="10">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: your fiddle allowing character "e"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
 $("#txtAge").keydown(function (e) {
       if(e.key=='e' || e.key=='.' || e.key=='-')
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the question was posted around 2013. Anyways, now type="number" is restricting alphabets and special characters other that 'e','.' and '+' as 'e' and '.' are considered for exponential numbers like 1.2e+12, '.' is considered for decimal numbers.

Comment: latest firefox as of this date does not support this

Comment: Great for "." decimals, but half the world uses "," and type="number" doesn't behave predictably cross browser. If you do have to support different languages be aware of this. Chrome uses the culture set in the browser, some versions of Firefox use the lang attribute.  I've resorted to input="text" with pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" as I haven't found a nice solution for this yet.

Answer (score 0):

just add - min="0" max="9" onkeydown="return false;"

**`<input type="number" id="txt_number" maxlength="70" name="txt_name" placeholder="Number"  min="0" max="9" onkeydown="return false;">`**