# HTML5 <input type="number"> pattern for integers only

Tags: regex, html

My code is very simple:

```
<input id="myID" type="number" pattern="^\d*$">
```

Based on a famous online regex test website, it should only let me write numbers, like 1 and 123, but not strings like 1a and 2e.

Instead it lets me write the letter "e". I guess it's for scientific notation? I don't need it. I just need integer numbers. How can I do this?

I've also tried ^[0-9]*$ but it still lets me write the letter "e". This happens on Chrome.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ty8nc4r4/)

Comment: Use `type="text"`

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew, I tried this but it doesn't work; it lets me write anything now. The pattern doesn't get applied.

Comment: Yes, you may type, but you may not submit, that is what `pattern` attribute is for. It is used for *final*, on-submit, validation

Comment: I use  onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" for that.

Comment: Well, just found another, maybe also relevant, [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224064/dont-allow-typing-alphabetic-characters-in-a-input-type-number).

Comment: Is it really the best option to use a jQuery plugin just for this? The link is broken...