# Store random value, $_SESSION and $_POST issue

Tags: php, html, session, post

I'm making something similar a captha, the not working part is the IF, under if(isset($_POST['submit'])), that always returns false. I think.
Tried a lot ways with no luck...
Anyway, I have followed this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/21504949/4167976 without success.

Here is my test php and html:

```
<?php
session_start();
$char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
$code = $char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)];
$_SESSION["testcode"] = $code;
echo $_SESSION["testcode"]."<br>"; // echo here only for testing

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $code1 = mb_substr($_POST['fullcode'], 0, 5);
    $code2 = mb_substr($_POST['fullcode'], -6);

    if ($code2 == $_SESSION["testcode"])
        {echo "The code is correct!";}
    else
        {echo "Wrong code!";}

    // unset($_SESSION['testcode']); // ???
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fullcode">
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Please, tell me what and where I'm wrong... Thanks! :)

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["testcode"])) {
    $char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    $code = $char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)];
    $_SESSION["testcode"] = $code;
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $code1 = mb_substr($_POST['fullcode'], 0, 5);
    $code2 = mb_substr($_POST['fullcode'], -6);

    if ($code2 === $_SESSION["testcode"])
        {echo "The code is correct!<br>";}
    else
        {echo "Wrong code!<br>";}

    unset($_SESSION['testcode']);
    $char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    $code = $char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)];
    $_SESSION["testcode"] = $code;
}
?>
```

Finally, get a new code IF the condition is false!

Comment: You overwrite the test code on every load, `$_SESSION["testcode"] = $code`. Check first if it was submitted.

Comment: Besides what @chris85 said; assign that session to a hidden input and then compare it. You may have to use a separate page also.

Comment: its not better to store value in $_SESSION instead in a hidden text field?

Comment: @Devilix the hidden input would be for testing only and should be removed from final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();

// first request.
// if not set session 'testcode' and set it, else do nothing.
// prevent session be covered.
if (!isset($_SESSION["testcode"])) {
    reFreshCode();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $code1 = mb_substr($_POST['fullcode'], 0, 5);
    $code2 = mb_substr($_POST['fullcode'], -6);
    if ($code2 == $_SESSION["testcode"])
        echo "The code is correct!";
    else {
        // get a new code IF the condition is false!
        echo "Wrong code!";
        echo “new code：”.reFreshCode();
    }
}

function reFreshCode() {
    $char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    $code = $char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)];
    return $_SESSION["testcode"] = $code;
}
```

Comment: Is working fine, but if the code is wrong, why does not generate another new? There is always the same...

Comment: one client generate one session id until unset it. so you can get client status. like login or logout.

Comment: i do not know your needs. a simple example, create a reset button .link a php file , unset($_SESSION);

Comment: i should make this under isset($_POST['submit']) to get a new code:

unset($_SESSION['testcode']);
$char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
$code = $char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)].$char[rand(0,35)];
$_SESSION["testcode"] = $code;

Comment: Sorry, can you explain a moment why with the function method i don't need to unset session to get a new code? Its weird... :(