# Html input type that only accepts float or integer numbers

Tags: html, validation, input, number-formatting

Hi friends I was wondering if there is an html input type that only accepts float or integer values and does not accept other characters such as letters and so on. I tried input type as number  but it also accepts other characters. If possible could you help me with this please?

Comment: Which browser accepts letters for `<input type="number">`? Sounds very wrong if what you're saying is true.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011861/is-there-a-float-input-type-in-html5?rq=1) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808590/html5-number-input-type-that-takes-only-integers?rq=1).

Comment: Are you trying to prevent users from even typing letters? Or do you just want the form to reject the values with error? What is your current code?

Comment: Please don't post a question that you haven't tried to solve. You should attempt to solve it yourself first. If you have tried, you can then include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: Well I just wrote    <form>                                                                       <input type="number"> </form> I thought it will accept only numbers but it also accepts letters.Both for Chrome and Firefox it accepts letters.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such type but you can use HTML5 pattern attribute and validate it using Regex.
Example :

```html
<form action="#">
<input type="text" pattern="[\d]+" title="Numbers">
<input type="Submit" value="Validate">
</form>
```

If you want to learn more about regex and pattern attribute check this link : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp