# How to avoid Decimal values in input type number

Tags: html

How to avoid Decimal values from input of Number in HTML5. Currently it allows user to type decimal value.

Comment: This question has been aswered already: [html5 number input type that takes only integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808590/html5-number-input-type-that-takes-only-integers)

Comment: I tried the pattern method, But i would like to have behaviour same as number field. in case of using pattern it doesn't validate until the value is submitted. Just like a number field doesn't allow user to type alphabets, is there any way i could stop period value too.

Answer (score 128):

An alternative to the supplied answers is to monitor the keypress while in the input. I personally like leaving the `type="number"` as an attribute. Here's a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kneeki/kaLbL2e0/)

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  Numbers: <input name="num" 
                  type="number"
                  min="1"
                  step="1"
                  onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"
                  title="Numbers only">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This solution works great to avoid inputs other than numbers [0-9]. Perfect.

Comment: It looks like this also disables backspace and delete keys in FireFox which isnt ideal when editing the input field.

Comment: you can still right-click paste to inject other inputs.

Comment: This solution isn't working on Android. Did anyone find a way to fix this on Android?

Answer (score 49):

I ended up checking to see if a user types in a period then preventing the event from propagating.

**Edit**: A better approach. The key press event has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress). Also added in a regex to strip out everything but numbers [0-9] on paste.

```html
<input type="number" onkeydown="if(event.key==='.'){event.preventDefault();}"  oninput="event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]*/g,'');">
```

Caution Experimental. Only partially works on chrome:
Wanted to look at a great way to grab the pasted value strip everything out then have it placed in input as normal. With the above method you are relying on the event order to correct the input, then any event listeners will ideally fire after. The onpaste method will fire before the input event fires so you keep the flow of events correct. However when replacing the string with only numbers the decimal point would still sneak in. Looking to update this when I find a better solution.

```html
<input type="number" onkeydown="if(event.key==='.'){event.preventDefault();}" onpaste="let pasteData = event.clipboardData.getData('text'); if(pasteData){pasteData.replace(/[^0-9]*/g,'');} " >
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Anyway, just a tip for Angular developers. onpaste is not allowed on input field, you have to use (paste) which does the same stuff as onpaste. Moreover, do not use event.* into onkeydown because, as Steven as said, is deprecaded. Instead i suggest to use $event on Angular application that should act as the same of event

Comment: Not sure if I'd want "3.14" to be pasted as "314".

Comment: You could just as easily set it to blank (or a default value) if that behavior is desired

Answer (score 18):

Use **pattern** attribute

```
<input type="number" name="num" pattern="[0-9]" title="Numbers only">
```

For more details http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/741o5pvj/)

Comment: Just a note: This seems to only validate on submit of the form that the input is in; it doesn't prevent decimal input, nor does it indicate that the field is in error before the form is submitted.

Comment: Secondary note: 1.0 will return as valid which may or may not correct depending on your what you want.

Comment: does not work as I want to check for decimals to be not included when user is typing.

Answer (score 15):

Just plain example using parseInt()

```html
<input type="number" oninput="this.value=(parseInt(this.value)||0)" placeholder="0-9" autofocus='' value='0' />
```

Comment: works well. still allows the user to enter a 'fullstop' or 'period' character because `parseInt(0.)` returns `0`. but that makes sense mathematically, because when you enter `0.` without a number after the decimal, the assumption is that it's zero, so `0.` == `0.0`, which equals `0 ` when parsed to an integer. makes sense to me anyway...

Comment: This works well but not actual since html5. Only if old browsers support is critical

Comment: this does not help as it can save `3` as `3.`

Comment: This works but then keep in mind the user won't be able to enter a dash `-` which means they cannot enter negative numbers

Answer (score 11):

Based on other answers here, I tried this:

```html
<input id="storeId" min="0" pattern="[0-9]" onkeypress="return !(event.charCode == 46)" step="1" title="Must be an integer number" type="number" >
```

I just blocked input of dot, but again this does not block paste.

ASCII DOT . character is 46

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="number" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 190">
```

This will Restrict period(.) input.For any Key restriction:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Comment: On my side, if the use the dot on my numpad, the keyCode is 110. If I use the one with the letters, it's 190. I think both should be restricted.

Answer (score 3):

`event.key` and `event.charCode` are deprecated features and don't work well with mobile virtual keyboards. I've done some research and this seems to be the easiest way to make it work.
Tested in Chrome and Firefox on Windows, in Chrome on Android and in Safari on iOS and seems to be working perfectly.

```js
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener('beforeinput', e => {
  if (!(Number(e.data) >= 0 && Number(e.data) <= 9)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
/* unnecessary */
#myInput {
width: 24ch;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="only a number can go here" id="myInput">
```

By the way, this is my first post here, so please tell me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: on mobile, this is the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You guys can try this
This function does not allow user to paste unwanted characters and also disallow user to enter .+-E

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById("inputBox");
            
                var invalidChars = [
                    "-",
                    "+",
                    "e",
                    "."
                ];

                inputBox.addEventListener("input", function() {
                    this.value = this.value.replace(/[e\+\-\.]/gi, "");
                });
                

                inputBox.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
                    if (invalidChars.includes(e.key)) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
```

```html
<input type="number" id="inputBox" >
```

`

If **error** occured in your JS. You can add this 
`[**$(document).ready(function() { code });**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgqvh.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<input type="number"  value=""  min="0" oninput="this.value=(parseInt(this.value)||0)" onkeypress="return !(event.charCode == 45||event.charCode == 46||event.charCode == 43)"  class="form-control" step="any" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"  name="quantity">
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex can help sort with this issue .

```
var re = new regExp('[.]+) ;
if(!re.test(num)){listOfNumbers.push(num)};
```

not letting the user type in a '.' on the input might not be a viable option when you are dealing with multiple cultures and interpretations of '.'.

Answer (score 0):

```
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57 || charCode==46))
        return false;
    return true;     
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31249995)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still wondering a solution, here's a workaround I came up with:

```
const val = 33.15;

console.log(String(val).includes(".")) // true

if(String(val).includes(".")){
   // the number is decimal
} else {
  // the number is not decimal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution let user insert only numbers from 0 to 9

```
<input type="number" name="intero" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')" />
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to provide more information as to how the code you've provided works, what you have changed, etc. Code-only answers might solve the problem of the original asker but they don't help future readers understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for Angular 16, the sample rejects negative numbers also

```
 <input matInput type="number" placeholder="Price" required 
                   onkeydown="if(this.key==='.'){this.preventDefault();}"
                   oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value.replace(/[^0-9]*/g,''))">
```

if you want it to accept negative number you can use

```
 <input matInput type="number" placeholder="Price" required formControlName="LimitPrice"
                   onkeydown="if(this.key==='.'){this.preventDefault();}"
                  >
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same challenge and a combination of answers here helped me to get it to work on Android, iOS and Chrome and Firefox on the desktop. I needed the input field to only accept numeric values without decimals. This is what I came up with:

```html
<input id="inputField" type="number" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

```js
document.getElementById("inputField").addEventListener('beforeinput', event => {
  const char = event.data;
  if (char != null && char !== '' && !/^[0-9]*$/.test(char)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

It's pretty similar to the [solution proposed by TyphousCrane654](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74965994/1778121). The differences are that it does not allow for decimal numbers and it also allows for the backspace button being pressed. It's also good to mention that it supports pasting in valid values, but not invalid values. I hope it helps someone else (or at least myself in the future).

You can test it yourself in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1qtgL0p2/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but seems to work.
Allows free edit, corrects on lose focus.

For range between -100 to 100

```html
<input 
onblur="val = parseInt(this.value.replace(/[^-0-9]/g, '')) || ''; this.value = Math.min(Math.max(val, -100), 100);"
oninput="val = parseInt(this.value.replace(/[^-0-9]/g, '')) || ''; this.value = val ? Math.min(Math.max(val, -100), 100) : '';">
```

Answer (score -1):

You should post what you have tried when asking questions.

To use integers only, change the following attribute.

```
step="any"
```

to

```
step="1"
```

Comment: using step attribute still allows user to type decimal value. Just like number field doesn't allow user to type alphabets, is there any way that i could restrict user to type float values

Answer (score -1):

```
 For Angular Developers:
    
    <input type="number" min="1" (keydown)="keyDown($event)">
    
    keyDown(event) {
        if (event.key === '.' || 'e' || 'E') {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
```

Answer (score -3):

`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.num, new { @class = "form-control input-sm",@maxlength = 5 ,@oninput = "this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');"})`

In MVC, above solution works.

Comment: Please provide more detail and context to this answer.

Comment: in addition to @Beefster comment, please also read the comments under the question, you would see that Kumar already rejected the regex approach

Comment: @NimaNr But for this form submission is not required