# How to force the user to put only numbers

Tags: javascript, validation, forms

I want the user to only be able to use input for numbers I've tried several things like `oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')` and a lot more but for example the code I sent if I type a letter and keep pressing the letter on the keyboard it won't turn it to anything, I need a code that will 100% force the user to type only numbers doesn't matter what happens. if I could put a number in the input box that the user cant delete for example 0 it will be good to.

Comment: Please, add a [mcve] by [edit]ing your question. It's important to show the HTML used in the input and your current or former tries. It's hard to help you by having nothing to base on.

Comment: Is this an HTML form the user would be filling out? If so, you could try
<input type="number">

Comment: @DerekK No you can write e and . in it

Comment: @CalvinNunes All I need is how do i write 0 in the input and won't let the user delete it

Comment: Ok, but, what you've tried? Can we see your code and then help debugging it and find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<input type=...>` as mentioned in the [input specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number).

Comment: It is not an answer, please review: [answer]

Comment: ? The question was how to allow user to write only numbers. I answe the question. Not sure what part is agaist the rule :)

Comment: @PavelKratochvil I mean only numbers without e and .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043867/how-to-avoid-decimal-values-in-input-type-number this thread could be also helpful

Comment: You didn't answer. He's trying to put only numbers in a input (that we don't even know how it is created) and your answer don't explain what he should do and why it will help him. You just pointed a link saying to "use the specs". It is more a comment than a real answer. But, it's up to you to let it here

Comment: I have just give him source to study. That is in my opinion best way how to give answers.. For sure you can say do it this way and post a code but what everyone already knows how to use ctrl+c and ctrl+v, you know.. :D

Comment: For what it's worth, your answer looked, at first glance, to not be an answer. It **is** an answer. Maybe it's only a partial answer, but it's not quite just a comment either. I've edited it to make it more of an answer.

Comment: Thanks for edit :) this is what i meant with my original answer. But seems like i chose wrong words to express myself.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to accomplish this but one of them would be capturing the keypress itself and returning `false` if the input is not a number.

Also if I understand you correctly, to add a default value of "0", just define it in the input directly like `value="0"`, or you could use a `placeholder="0"` if that's what you're looking for.

```html
<input type="number" value="0" onkeydown="javascript: return event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46 ? true : !isNaN(Number(event.key))" />
```

Answer (score 0):

While this wouldn't enforce the user input to numbers only, you *may* want to consider using the [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_against_a_regular_expression) attribute to leverage some built-in behaviour. If you type non-numeric characters, the text colour will turn red:

```css
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+"/>
```

Then we can start looking at the [constraint validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_against_a_regular_expression):

> The Constraint Validation API enables checking values that users have entered into form controls, before submitting the values to the server.

If you type non-numeric characters and try to submit the form, you should see a built-in tooltip displaying a custom error message:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('invalid', () => {
  if (input.validity.patternMismatch) {
    input.setCustomValidity('Numbers only please!!');
  }
});
```

```css
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+"/>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: But you see the problem with your code is that if i type text for example: ABC and i hit the submit I can not put a number after I put text and it's getting bugged

Answer (score 0):

```js
      $("#but").click(function(){
        let inp_val = $("#txt").val();
        if(isNaN(inp_val)){
          alert("Just enter a number.");
          $("#txt").val("");
        }
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt">
<input type="button" value="CLICK" id="but">
```