# How to make type=“text” not to key Minus sign (-)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use input type=text, but only keyin number, how to no allow user keyin Minus sign (-)?

```
<input required type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="discount" placeholder='not allow negative'  >
```

Comment: Use JS, and parse value with `inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, inputValue)`

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808590/html5-number-input-type-that-takes-only-integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change from

```
<input required type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="discount" placeholder='not allow negative' >
```

to

```
<input required type="text" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" name="discount" placeholder='not allow negative' >
```

Answer (score 3):

Just make the type number and add min attribute, so your code must be like this

```
<input type="number" min="0"/>
```