# Decimal is ignored in type="number" when there are no numbers after it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2zopmgjz/2/) that removes the last character from the input when the user types `.`
However it seems `.length` ignores the decimal when there are no numbers after it.

For example: currently when the user types `20.`, it will be cut to `2` instead of `20`.

How can I detect this and remove the decimal once the user types it?

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/hL8ca6zp/

Comment: You should post this as answer. Can be useful to others.

Comment: @engineeriscool thanks for the comment! Unfortunately I'm looking for a solution where the input also has the attribute `type="number"`.

Comment: @engineeriscool You can still enter some numbers and then put cursor in front and put '.'

Comment: @vabii just change `slice` to `.replace(/\./g,'')`

Comment: The issue is what `type="number"` validates as a number, even when doing `$(this).val($(this).val().replace(".",""))` the problem is that `.val()` won't include the `.` because `20.` is an invalid number so `.value` will be `20`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5: number input type that takes only integers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808590/html5-number-input-type-that-takes-only-integers)

Answer (score 1):

I think your requirement is to ignore it when a user types the period.

So all you need is this (notice the event is on `keydown` and not `keyup`):

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 190 || e.keyCode == 110){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Or, even easier, [attribute the input so it only takes whole numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808590/html5-number-input-type-that-takes-only-integers):

```
<input type="number" min="0" step="1"/>
```