# Validating HTML input field

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

I am currently doing a project which was last worked on a couple of years ago. As there has been no knowledge transfer to me, it's all kind of convoluted for me.

The app uses AngularJS. I have a bootstrap pager, which has a `Jump to page: [ ]` field. Currently, that field accepts both integers and decimals, and I obviously don't want decimal page numbers.

I know I could try to find somewhere in JS to validate the input, but **I'm looking for a way to validate input inside html - more precisely, to check if some input is integer.**

My HTML element is:

```
<div style="float:right;margin-right:10px;">
<span style="float:right">Jump to page:</span>
<br/>
<div class="col-xs-5" style="float:right">
    <input class="form-control" id="navPageField" type="text"
           ng-model="pager.pageToNavigate"
           snp-enter="pager.navigateToPage(pager.pageToNavigate)"
           tooltip="page {{pager.currentPage}} / {{pager.pageCount}}"
           tooltip-trigger tooltip-animation="true" tooltip-placement="bottom" />
</div>
```

EDIT: Solved it by adding `pattern="^[0-9]*$"` to the input element. `type=number` did not work as expected for me, even when adding `step="1"`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808590/html5-number-input-type-that-takes-only-integers

Comment: This is what happens when backend is forced to do frontend... :(