# How to only allow whole numbers in input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, input

I'm having trouble only allowing positive whole numbers for an input.

I checked other people's questions, but they don't seem to work.

```
<input type="number" class="btn-group" placeholder = "People:" id="divideBy">
```

I use both jquery or javascript if those are needed for this to work.

Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808590/html5-number-input-type-that-takes-only-integers) doesn't work for you?

Comment: It doesn't show how to do it, none of the answers work.

Comment: Changing your code to `<input type="number" min="0" step="1"/>` doesn't work?

Comment: can always prevent default when user enters a decimal: https://codepen.io/PavlosKaralis/pen/pogweGW?editors=1010