# Restrict typing decimal point in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to restrict the user to type decimal point as below.

```
 <b-form-input
          size="sm"
          type="number"
          v-model.number="lots"
          class="inputprice"
          style="width:40%"
          oninput="javascript: if (this.value === '.') return;"
        >{{ lots }}
 </b-form-input>
```

But this attempt not working. Anyone knows how can I do it inside on input attribute?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? allow only integers?

Comment: yes, only positive integers

Comment: Related answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8808608/104380

Comment: There also able to type dot

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the input value to an integer as follows:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data(){
    return{
      lots:0
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input
    type="number"
    v-model.number="lots"
    class="inputprice"
    style="width:40%"
    oninput="this.value = parseInt(this.value);"
  />{{ lots }}
</div>
```

Comment: Here also able to type dot right?

Comment: @M.Cooper yes but it will directly parse it to an integer

Comment: Thanks. But I need to restrict typing dot

Comment: @M.Cooper this does prevent the dot.