# The input from client side should entered only digits, if is alphabets should give an error msg

Tags: javascript, html

Create an html page with the following form:

```html
<form method="post" name="example" action="">
  <p> Enter your name <input type="text"> </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Information" />
</form>
<div id="a"></div>
```

Add a js validation function to the form that ensures that you can only add numbers in the textbox If you enter alphabets, you should generate an error message in the given div. -->

I run the requirement successfully and I'm giving the error message when it entered alphabets. However, it's giving me the same error message when I enter digits as well. Please kindly show how the function or the window.onload should be implemented. Thank you.

My answer is down below;

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let form = document.getElementById('form_ref')
  form.onsubmit = function() {
    let user = form.user.value;
    if (parseInt(user) !== user) {
      document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = "Error! Please enter digits only!";
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form_ref" method="post" name="example" action="">
  <label for="username">User</label><input type="text" name="user" id="username" required>
  <div id="a"></div>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Information" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: google w3 input number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number input type that takes only integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808590/number-input-type-that-takes-only-integers) `if (parseInt(user) !== user) {` is a strict type comparison, so you're checking if `int value === string value` which will always be false. Either loosening this restriction, implementing regex validation, or using default HTML `number` functionality are possible solutions here.

Answer (score 0):

Your equality check `parseInt(user) !== user` will always return `true` because `form.user.value` is a string but `parseInt(...)` always returns an integer. If you want to check if the entry is an integer there are a couple ways.


You can change the input's `type` attribute to `number` to make sure only digits can be entered and then you just have to make sure it's an integer and not a decimal (`type="number"` still allows decimal numbers so not just digits). `user` will still be a string, but it's easier to check. I'd recommend using `Number.isInteger(...)` to do the checking:

```
if (!Number.isInteger(parseFloat(user))) {
```

If you really want to use `type="text"` you can iterate through `user` and make sure its characters are all digits:

```
for(let i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
  if("0123456789".indexOf(user[i]) == -1) {
    document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = "Error! Please enter digits only!";
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

One advantage of this method is that you can make more characters available if you want to just by adding them to the string that's searched in the iteration. A disadvantage is that it's slower than the other method (the `indexOf` method has to iterate through the string for every character of `user`), but for your use case that seems irrelevant-- this function doesn't need to be called many times per second as it's a simple login type of thing, and it's client-side so you don't need to handle many instances at once. If speed is an issue you could probably make a comparison to the integer equivalencies of the characters:

```
if(user.charCodeAt(i) < "0".charCodeAt(0) || user.charCodeAt(i) > "9".charCodeAt(0)) {
```